# AdbWireless application has failed

Tags: adbwireless

Hopefully someone else out there is familiar with this, I'm trying to custom-script my adbwireless app but it keeps returning code 7. Where is a setting where I can enable debug mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For windows, you'll find it in C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Temp\adb.log.